# How to use JHtml::booleanlist with btn-group

Tags: joomla-3.4, bootstrap, jhtml

In the front-end I have a code as below

```
jimport( 'joomla.html.html.select' );
echo JHtmlSelect::booleanlist('published',null,$this->book->published,'Yes','No')
```

What I see is as below

[image]

What I would like to see as

[image]

Comment: Can you try to wrap the "echo JHtmlSelect::booleanlist..." part in a div with class "btn-group btn-group-yesno"?

Comment: See https://docs.joomla.org/Radio_form_field_type and use the class as suggested on this page

Answer (score 2):

It would be better to just load a `JFormFieldRadio` it will take care of required scripts.

```
JFormHelper::loadFieldClass('radio');

$field = new JFormFieldRadio();
$field->setup(new SimpleXMLElement('<field name="published" type="radio" size="1" default="0" class="btn-group btn-group-yesno"><option value="0">JNO</option><option value="1">JYES</option></field>'), 1);

echo $field->renderField(array('hiddenLabel'=>true));
```

This will work on a back-end. If you are trying to make it work on front-end it is possible you will need to update your template too.